# Setting up Wi-Fi using USB adapter on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, usb

I have tried in vain to set up my Ubuntu 12.04 laptop as a Wi-Fi hotspot; it says

> Your wireless card does not support Access Point mode

I had to resort to a USB Wi-Fi adapter, and I purchased this one:

> Leoxsys Leo Nano150N 802.11n 150Mbps USB wireless Nano adapter

It works fine on Windows and is also detected by my Android. However, I have not been able to spring it to life on Ubuntu 12.04 after having scoured through almost infinite sources on the Internet. I have downloaded the drivers from their official website meant for Ubuntu. I hope I have installed them correctly, though their description of how to install runs into several messy and confounding lines.

`lsusb` returns this

```
 Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp
```

so it is being detected.... perplexed with how to get it working; please help.